# find the count of occurrences of string in array list

Tags: java, arraylist

I have array list, i want to find the count of the occurrences of strings in the list  in java.

Suppose array list has

`good girl,
good boy,
very good girl,
she is good,
unwanted group,
unwanted list`

I want to get the count of the each occurence

Comment: What do you want the output to be? Do you want it to be a `HashMap` linking each string with its number of occurrences or have it be a function that takes a string and returns a single `int`?

Comment: What's the expected output? Each element only is in that list once

Comment: Some code would really help us find a solution along with you.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very explicit. What exactly is the expected output? Do you want to compute the occurences for each list at its own or all together?

In general you would use `Map`s to count occurrences. Like `HashMap`s, they allow a fast get-access.

Here's a small snippet that counts all word occurences of a given text:

```
final String input = "word word test word";
// Splits at word boundary
final String[] words = input.split("\\b");

final HashMap<String, Integer> wordToCount = new HashMap<>();
// Iterate all words
for (final String word : words) {
    if (!wordToCount.contains(word)) {
        // Word seen for the first time
        wordToCount.put(word, 1);
    } else {
        // Word was already seen before, increase the counter
        final int currentCounter = wordToCount.get(word);
        wordToCount.put(word, currentCounter + 1);
    }
}

// Output the word occurences
for (final Entry<String, Integer> entry : wordToCount.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Word: " + entry.getKey() + ", #: " + entry.getValue());
}
```

The output of this snippet will be something like:

```
Word: word, #: 3
Word: test, #: 1
```